# Where do the Dothraki keep their weapons if not in the sacred city?

Tags: game-of-thrones

The TV show mentions that people can't carry weapons in the Dothraki's sacred city.

I know their might not be a canon explanation for this, but I thought someone may know!

I was just thinking there looked like a hell of a lot of people lived/stay in the city so there must be a weapons store somewhere?

I just imagine that if there are no weapons allowed it means it would be quite easy for any invader to invade unless the weapons are close?

Wouldn't they be easy to steal unless heavily guarded it seems the Dothraki live by certain strict rules and honour is super important to Dothraki. So it's clear it's illegal.

The point is why would the Dothraki be so reckless?

Basically it would be easy to assault them, it's in a valley. You could just send a small team ahead to kill the guards on lookout then have an army raid the city

Dothraki have many enemies so I'm surprised it's still standing.

Are they literally just protected by the fact There are many Dothraki hordes who would revenge attack if someone attacked the city?

Liked I said canon answers preferred but not needed.

Just curious on opinions.

Comment: I don’t know for sure, but is it possible that weapons are simply stored outside the city? As such, if an army approached, they’d have plenty of time to leave the city and defend themselves with their weapons (And it really is quite hard to hide an army. Those things are large and they move *slowly*).

Answer (score 3):

The only canon explanation would be outside the city but to expand the city is most likely surrounded at all times by different khalisar's, a few people at all times would have to be outside the city to tend to the horses or to tend to the slaves who are tending the horses the weapons are most likely kept in their camps

I am not certain about the show but IIRC in the books the city is a holy city it isnt really a living city more of a place where the Dothraki come to trade among themselves and perform holy ceremonies the only permanent residents are the wifes of dead khal's it is also located in the middle of the Dothraki Sea which would mean attacking it would be logistical hell as well as impossible to keep the fact that an army is coming a secret.

Attacking the city would not actually do anything the Dothraki are nomadic even if the only Dothraki city has a permanent population numbering say %20 of the total Dothraki population the remaining %80 would utterly annihilate the city(s) responsible and do unspeakable things to its/their leaders.

While people may dislike the Dothraki they are still an intricate part of the economy and even if a single city raised the numbers and managed to wipe them out that city would be easy meat for the others (its also highly doubtful you would get the level of cooperation for multiple cities to raise an army together)

Answer (score 2):

The premise of your question is flawed: there is no prohibition on *carrying* weapons in [Vaes Dothrak](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160171/where-do-the-dothraki-keep-their-weapons-if-not-in-the-sacred-city) only on unsheathing them and shedding blood. Likewise, there is also no prohibition on violence as the death of [Viserys Targaryen](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Viserys_Targaryen) demonstrates.

Comment: His premise isn't flawed based on the text. Here are four quotes from the book regarding Vaes Dothrak: "... the princess nears Vaes Dothrak, where it is death to draw a blade" (Varys), "it was forbidden to carry a blade in Vaes Dothrak, or to shed a free man's blood" (Dany, describing Jorah's words), "No steel was permitted within the sacred confines of Vaes Dothrak ... she had to rip the heart" (Dany), "No one may carry a blade here or shed a man's blood" (Jorah). The distinction that carrying is permitted seems contradictory since the characters specifically use the word "carry" as a no-no.

Comment: Also, being able to kill someone by not-blood-shedding works when you're dealing with a 1v1, random fight, assassinating someone etc. It would be a horrific disadvantage in a battle against an army using weapons, which is where his question is going.